# What does the punctuation in include_path mean?

Tags: php

In the php menue http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.include-path

Example #1 Unix include_path

```
include_path=".:/php/includes"
```

`.` means the current directory , what does `:` mean here?

Example #2 Windows include_path

```
include_path=".;c:\php\includes"
```

`.` means the current directory , what does `;` mean here?

Comment: It's just a the separator between values. It differs between those OS's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is path separator that in PHP can access by `PATH_SEPARATOR` constant. It is possible to extend the include path regardless of the operating system. It can be used in autoload(PHP):

```
    define("APPLICATION_PATH",realpath("."));
    $include_path = array(
        APPLICATION_PATH,
        realpath(APPLICATION_PATH."/controller"),
        get_include_path()
    );
    set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR,$include_path));
```

Answer (score 1):

It's the [path separator](http://php.net/manual/en/dir.constants.php). To add directories to the include path, you can use the following syntax as referenced [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-include-path.php)

```
$path = '/usr/lib/pear';
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . $path);
```